# PC won't recognize bootable usb for windows 8.1

Tags: windows, boot, usb

I am building my first pc from scratch in quite a while now.

I purchased Win 8.1 online and made a bootable usb with it. When I was trying to install the OS to the new PC, the PC won't recognize it as boot media and just keeps asking me to "insert boot media to selected boot device and press a key" over and over again.

The weird thing is that if I insert the USB then start the pc it goes straight to the Win 8.1 installation screen, but it just stops after choosing recommended/custom and says I have to restart the PC and try again because I started the PC with the USC already inserted.

ASUS z97x motherboard if it helps.

Honestly considering getting an optical drive and burn an ISO just so I can get it done ASAP...

Comment: How did you create the bootable usb stick?

Comment: @ap0 The windows download tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From personal exsperience, it can be a pain to install a new os from usb with a efi system.
This might or might not help you, but you could try the following:

1. Make sure you use a usb2 stick, and insert it into a usb2 port.
   Greater chance for success!
2. Make sure you boot the usb stick in efi and not in legacy bios mode.
   Most new motherboards I've tried, seems to try and boot new devices
   in legacy mode. Personally I've disabled legacy mode completely.
3. If that didn't help, try Microsoft own usb install tool.
   http://wudt.codeplex.com/

My personal favorite tool to make a bootable usb stick with is rufus: http://rufus.akeo.ie/

Hope it somehow helped.
Good luck!

Comment: I disabled legacy and tried to stall the os in custom instead of standard. It finally worked!